# Show array difference not working

Tags: php, arrays, compare

How do i compare the following two arrays?
When I use:

```
array_diff($array1, $array2)
```

it just shows all the arrays in $array1 not only 39077

```
Array1 ( [0] => 40016 [1] => 39995 [2] => 39990 [3] => 38921 [4] => 39890 [5] => 39812 [6] => 39672 [7] => 39767 [8] => 38709 [9] => 18631 [10] => 9503 ) 

Array2 ( [0] => 40016 [1] => 39995 [2] => 39990 [3] => 38921 [4] => 39890 [5] => 39812 [6] => 39672 [7] => 39767 [8] => 38709 [9] => 18631 [10] => 9503 [11] => 39077 )
```

If I use array_diff_keys, I can cheat it with 1234 as value in array1 because that function only checks how many keys not what values.

```
Array1 ( [0] => 40016 [1] => 39995 [2] => 39990 [3] => 38921 [4] => 39890 [5] => 39812 [6] => 39672 [7] => 39767 [8] => 38709 [9] => 18631 [10] => 9503 [11] => 1234) 

Array2 ( [0] => 40016 [1] => 39995 [2] => 39990 [3] => 38921 [4] => 39890 [5] => 39812 [6] => 39672 [7] => 39767 [8] => 38709 [9] => 18631 [10] => 9503 [11] => 39077 )
```

the output will be

```
array()
```

Comment: This is still unclear, but if you want `39077` you need to swap the args `array_diff($array2, $array1)`

Comment: But then It just shows all the values in array2, before it was all in $array1 not the difference between

Comment: No it doesn't.  Yours shows empty and swapped shows `39077`: https://3v4l.org/aUtQ1 Are you sure you're not actually running `array_intersect()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is correct the PHP manual 
http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-diff.php
say  that date_diff

> Compares array1 against one or more other arrays and returns the
>   values in array1 that are not present in any of the other arrays.

and is specific for simple  array  and  not for  key (associative) array .. so for key array not work

Could be you need

```
  array_diff_key($array1, $array2)
```

that

> array_diff_key — Computes the difference of arrays using keys for
>   comparison

or for value you can use  array_diff_assoc

```
 array_diff_assoc($array1, $array2);
```

Comment: Thanks scaisEdge, great function :)

Comment: I know how, have to wait 5 more minutes :)

Comment: What if i need to compare the values instead?

Comment: Explain  better   .. what do you  mean ..?

Comment: If I add a word/number to array1 it will mark it as no differents between array 1 and array2 because it not checks the values only how many keys / length / counts

Comment: This seems another question  to me  and te proper   way in this case is post a new well decribed  question with proper specific  .. data sample .. the firts impressione seems a solution could be a foreach on an array that check also the second and mark properly the first array when you have posted  the new question eventually comment me so i can take a look

Comment: But is it not possible only to check the value and not how many keys with a one liner?

Comment: @Michael   .Really, it's very hard to understand a question from a simple comment. try to post an appropriate question, and above all full of a valid significant example

Comment: @Michael   . change the query after one correct answer  is not fair  ..

Comment: Sorry but that was after I have tested it.

Comment: array_diff_assoc gives no different, how do I make a simple array. I use $array3 = array();  $array3[] = $value; in a loop

Comment: Yes for some situation you can use a foreach  over a an array  ..and use the value for foreach for check over the other array and return the result in a 3th array  ..

Comment: but array_diff_assoc  should give your the 11=>1234

Comment: it does not :( hmmm I think theres something wrong with my array

Comment: remember that is alway the first array compared with the second .. and the difference is showed for th firts ..

Comment: It turns out that there was a problem with one of my arrays, it was loaded from a txt file with file(), with fopen it now works with array_diff

Answer (score 0):

> it just shows all the arrays in $array1 not only 39077

Just interchange argument

```
array_diff($array2, $array1);
```

> **Note:** this answer will returns the values in $array2 that are not present in $array1, it will not return the values in $array1 that are
>   not in $array2.

**Example**

```
$ php -r '$a1=array(1,2,3,7,8); $a2=array(1,2,7,10,15); print_r(array_diff($a2,$a1));'
Array
(
    [3] => 10
    [4] => 15
)
```

**Input**

```
$ cat test.php 
<?php

$array1 = array( 40016 , 39995 , 39990, 38921 , 39890 , 39812 , 39672 , 39767 , 38709 , 18631 , 9503);
$array2 = array( 40016 , 39995 , 39990, 38921 , 39890 , 39812 , 39672 , 39767 , 38709 , 18631 , 9503, 39077);

print_r(array_diff($array2,$array1));

?>
```

**Output**

```
$ php test.php 
Array
(
    [11] => 39077
)
```

Comment: It will still not work, it will still not only show the only different between the two.

Comment: what is expected output

Comment: @Michael Did you interchange argument ?

Comment: I dont get the same output, maybe because you have created your array manually.

Comment: I use: $array = array();  and then loop in foreach $array[] = $value;

Comment: It should work, as you can see for given input you get 39077 as you expected, loop is alright, argument order is important, read my post once again